# PHP: Understanding string type juggling

Tags: php, casting

If I set `$var` to a `string` in PHP, that variable will evaluate to `true` in any conditions:

```
$var = "foo";
if ( $var ) {
    echo 'I will be printed';
} else {
    echo 'I will not be printed';
}
```

I understand that my condition above automatically does type juggling so that `$var` is converted in a `bool`.

Now, if I cast `$var` to an `integer`, I get `0`:

```
var_dump( (int)$var ); // int(0)
```

`0` is a **falsy** value which becomes `false` when converted to a `bool`:

```
$zero = 0;
var_dump( (bool)$zero ); // bool(false)
```

Considering the above, why doesn't my condition print "I will not be printed"?

Comment: This is [false](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php). An empty string, the string "0" and NULL. If the string is numerical, it will contain that value when cast to INT, otherwise it will be cast to 0 or FALSE.

Comment: Check this link for type comparisons : http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. I think Niet the Dark Absol's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34044476/1709033) below explains it. There's no intermediate step of converting to an `int` when the condition does the type juggling: it goes straight from a `string` to a `bool`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type juggling isn't lossless. It comes with potential loss of data.

For instance...

```
var_dump( strval(intval("foo"))); // string(1) "0"
```

But if you were to write...

```
if( "foo" == "0") // non-strict comparison intended
```

You would surely not expect it to run! And indeed it doesn't.

So because type changes come with data loss, you can't expect conversions to be equivalent. In other words, `boolval(intval($var))` and `boolval($var)` need not be the same.

If you want to be strict in your comparisons, use something like this:

```
if( is_string($var) && $var !== "") // is not the empty string
```

(Arguably `!==` is redundant and `!=` works fine, but arguably this whole condition is overkill)

Comment: so the condition type juggling mechanism converts the `string` directly to a `bool` with no intermediate step of converting to an `int`? That makes sense, and does explain why the condition expression evaluates to `true`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple test of truth:

```
$s = array( // bool  (int)cast
    '',     // FALSE int=0
    'Test', // TRUE  int=0
    '0.0',  // TRUE  int=0
    '124',  // TRUE  int=124
    '000',  // TRUE  int=0
    '0',    // FALSE int=0
    NULL    // FALSE int=0
);


foreach( $s as $var )
    echo $var . ' // ' 
        . ( $var ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE' ) . ' '
        . 'int=' . (int)$var . PHP_EOL;
```

In case of a string casting to bool, `FALSE` is an empty string, NULL and the value '0'. Everything else is `TRUE`. See the manual on [false](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

In your case, `$var` is a string "foo", which is not being converted to `FALSE` since it is neither NULL, "0" or "", therefore you will not get 'I will not be printed'.

If you cast it to an INT, everything is 0 except a pure numerical value.

Comment: Can I ask as to how this answers the question at hand?

Comment: @SamSwift웃: Quote henrywright  'why doesn't my condition print "I will not be printed"?' - because only the strings '', '0' and NULL is converted to `FALSE`. CHange the string and you will get "I will not be printed"

Comment: Thank you for clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

You will not get the `else` echo done, as a string that is not empty evaluates to true when used in an if, i.e.:

```
$foo = "Hello";
if ($foo)
    print "True"; //This will print as a string is true if not empty
else 
    print "False"; //Doesn't print as string is not empty
```

Try this:

```
$foo = "Hello";
if ((int)$foo)
    print "True";
else
    print "False"; //Will print as the string evaluates to 0 (false) as it is not an integer
```

Comment: @Uchiha, I did, but what I am trying to do is show what happens when a string is type casted to an int where it is of string value (a-z A-Z)