# PHP intval() weird result on basic calculation

Tags: php

Hello,

```
$expression="1*2";
var_dump(intval($expression));
```

gives int 1

why ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: What do you expect it to return?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: Understanding string type juggling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044348/php-understanding-string-type-juggling)

Comment: i expected 2 axiac

Comment: no emix i wanted to evaluate it, but it's recognized as a mathematic expression, and i'd like it to be

Comment: I found something here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880772/calculate-math-expression-from-a-string-using-eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880772/calculate-math-expression-from-a-string-using-eval)

Answer (score 2):

There is using common type cast rules. In string "1*2" second char is not numeric. Takes only left side.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#111523

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting the expression to be evaluated as an expression, use the eval() function.

But this is not recommended unless you filter $expression for dangerous characters.